# Want to save two buttons with Intent and redirect user on future button click on their first choice

Tags: android, android-intent, android-button

I have one Main Activity that has two Buttons:

1. first Button - *Creates an Ad*(`CreateAd_Activity`), if you want to
   rent a room, **before going to CreateAd_Activity, they go to Register Activity**
2. second Button - *Creates an Ad* (`CreateProfileAd_Activity`), if you have a room to rent, **before going to CreateAd_Activity, they go to Register Activity**

So no matter what button user clicks on , he will go to Register Activity

// This are Two Buttons that i have in my Main Activity with their onClick methods

```
    vreauCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Register.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    amCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Register.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

When i click on both of them, i have created an Intent to go to a Register User Activity.
After they complete some `EditTexts` with name, email,password etc  in Register Activity they have another Button called "register".

// Here is Register Activity with it`s components

```
EditText numeRegister;
EditText varstaRegister;
EditText adresaRegister;
EditText orasRegister;
EditText nrTelefonRegister;
EditText emailRegister;
EditText parolaRegister;
Button register;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    numeRegister = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_register_nume);
    varstaRegister = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_register_varsta);
    adresaRegister = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_register_adresa);
    orasRegister = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_register_oras);
    nrTelefonRegister = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_register_nrTelefon);
    emailRegister = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_register_email);
    parolaRegister = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_register_parola);
    register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_register_inregistreaza);

    register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // after user clicks on this button to be redirected on their first choice button , if they clicked on button amCamera to be redirected to CreateAd_Activity or if they clicked on button vreauCamera to be redirected to CreateProfileAd_Activity, 


        }
    });


}
```

}

I want that when i click on Button "register" to redirect me on their first choice

1. if in my Main Activity they have clicked on button vreauCamera first time, after they press on register button to be redirected to this activity: *CreateProfileAd_Activity*
2. if in my Main Activity they have clicked on button amCamera first time, after they press on register button to be redirected to this activity:
   *CreateAd_Activity*

Could you help me please ?

Thank you

Comment: What hace you tried? Plase show the significant part of your code. Help others help you.

Comment: We could help... but you didn't post any code so far.

Comment: Added some code. Hope this make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Manage to solve my question so i would like to post the way i did .

I used an Intent to send a String on one of my buttons :

```
vreauCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Register.class);
                i.putExtra("VreauCamera","VreauCamera");
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```

Then in my activity when i clicked on Button - " register " i used this code :

```
register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = getIntent();
                    String data = i.getStringExtra("VreauCamera");
                    if(data!=null){
                        i = new Intent(Register.this,CreateProfileAd.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }else if(data==null){
                        i = new Intent(Register.this,CreateAd.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }

                }
            });
```

Hope this will help somebody else too .